# Parameterized next pool impossible for class hierarchy of pooled objects?

Tags: c++, generics, haxe

With regards to the cpp tag. This pattern is relevant generally to parameterization, and can be implemented in C++ with templates. My primary query is whether this is a logically solveable pattern (which I believe it isn't as specified) in C++ and the AVM2, with a preference to solving it with haxe. The particular code sample and query in general, written in Haxe, compiles to the relevant C++ target in a logically identical way.

I am inquiring if there is fix to this pattern with:

1. Parameterization logic
2. There is some other way to maintain
   the link of free objects other than a next property close to the
   optimal implementation of a direct typed member access as
   facilitated by said next property (eg avoiding a reflective/switch call for access to the `next` member)
3. I am aware there are other
   pooling implementations, that is not what I am asking.

***Question:***

It would appear that there is no way to define a parameterized pool for a `Class` that extends from a `Class` that itself is pooled because the subclass cannot conform to `Poolable_i` interface because it cannot redefine the `next` property. Is this a valid conclusion?

> Ie: the a `Pool_pointer<Destination>` cannot exist because `Destination`
>   cannot conform to any useful constraint specified in `Pool_pointer<Destination>`

For instance:

```
Poolable_i<T> is a base that hase a single property next:T
Point3d implements Poolable_i<Point3d>
Destination extends Point3d {
    public var time:Time;
}
```

This is also presuming that you do not wish to use a base class that itself is parameterized, eg `Point3d_base<T:{Poolable_i<T>,Point3d_base}>` because one may require a hierarchy with a depth greater than 1.

Of course this can be solved in multiple ways with preprocessing as I intend to do. I am just curious if I am missing something with regards to the impossibility of said templating implementation.

```
package test.shared;
class Pool_pointer<T:Poolable_i<T>> implements Pool_i<T> {
    public var free:T;
    public function new() {
    }
    public function destroy():Void {
    }
    public inline function get():T {
        var r:T=null;
        if(free==null) {
            r=new T();
        } else {
            r=free;
            free=r.next;
        }
        return r;
    }
    public inline function put(v:T):Void {
        v.next=free;
        free=v;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's haxe which compiles to cpp. I am interested if the pattern is possible to implement in cpp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to parameterize the entire hierarchy with regards to functionality declarations and create typedefs/specific Classes for concrete implementations.

```
Destination_base<NextT> -> Destination extends Destination_base<Destination>
^
|
Point3d_base<NextT> -> Point3d extends Point3d_base<Point3d>
```

Implementation hierarchy is parameterized. Ugh. Love thy preprocessing.